# mysql count results not already present in previous months

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables, 1 table "months" and 1 table "ad". I would like to get all distinct emails from Ad per month where those emails are not already count in the previous months of the year.

I have sthg like that today :

```
SELECT months.id_month, Count(DISTINCT ad.email) 
FROM  `months` 
LEFT JOIN `ad` 
  ON id_month = Month(ad.created_at) 
 AND Year(ad.created_at) = 2015 
GROUP BY id_month 
ORDER BY id_month ASC
```

The output :

[image]

but for December, the 3 distinct emails found are already in November, and the expected output should be 0 for December.

Any idea?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com prepare sample data

Comment: here are sample data : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69302/1

Comment: Sample data to reproduce your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  It sounds like you want to count the first time an email appears in each year.  If so, then use two aggregations:

```
SELECT m.id_month, Count(ad.email) 
FROM  months m LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT ad.email, MIN(ad.created_at) as created_at_2015
       FROM `ad` 
       WHERE Year(ad.created_at) = 2015 
       GROUP BY ad.email
      ) ad
      ON m.id_month = Month(ad.created_at_2015) 
GROUP BY m.id_month 
ORDER BY m.id_month ASC ;
```